# URL object json NAGIOS

Tags: php, url, nagios, prtg

I have a question, I work with many monitoring web, if you know `PRTG` you can make a URL that returns the status of the various sensors and alarm messages, and process this information in different web graphic pages; Now I have been asked to do the same but with the tool Will they hear the `NAGIOS` process? I do not understand how it should build the URL if alguin worked with this I would appreciate help me.

Example URL with `PRTG`:

```
https://10.213.8.25/api/table.json?content=sensors&output=json&columns=status,message&filter_status=4&filter_objid=9336&filter_objid=9495&filter_objid=9496
```

Return:

```
{"prtg-version":":","treesize":000,"sensors":[{"objid":1001.....}]}
```

Comment: Core nagios? Nope. If you're using Check_MK or OMD you can call the livestatus API. I use this library: https://github.com/aashley/nagios-livestatus-client

Answer (score 0):

You can get JSON starting with Nagios Core version **4.0.7**.
Just browse to **`http://<address_of_your_nagios_server>/nagios/jsonquery.html`**
and you'll find a **JSON Query Generator** page that can help your build your query URL, execute it, and get JSON results.  After executing the query, on the right-hand side of the page, the generated URL will be given and below it, the results of the query.  You can paste the generated URL into a browser or call from your application to get raw JSON.

More information on this feature can be found here: https://labs.nagios.com/2014/06/19/exploring-the-new-json-cgis-in-nagios-core-4-0-7-part-1/